# Identity on vector fields.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Given $X,Y$ smooth vector fields on a manifold $M$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ I want to prove that $X(f)Y=Y(f)X$, because if that's true it will make some calculations a lot easier in another problem I'm solving, but i don't even know if it's true, by now what I've been using that $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n Y^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ and similar for $X$, but that doesn't get me to anything.
If it's true i would appreciate a hint to get the result.

Comment: That's absolutely not true, $X$ and $Y$ can be linearly independent (hell, they could even happen to be orthogonal relative to some Riemannian metric on $M$). We're missing a lot of information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter example: $M = \Bbb R^2$, $X = \partial_x$, $Y = \partial_y$ and $f(x,y) = x$.
One has $X(f)Y = \partial_y$ and $Y(f)X = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed I was skipping a Leibniz rule somewhere in my process, so the claim I made isn't necessary to solve the real problem.